# Trying to code a short intro for my app

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm trying to code a short intros for my first app.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var MainscrollView = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MainscrollView.delegate = self

        //Frames
        var singleFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame;

        var scrollFrame : CGRect = singleFrame
        scrollFrame.size.width *= 3.0 //num. frames

        //Views

        //ScrollView
        MainscrollView = UIScrollView(frame: singleFrame)
        view.addSubview(MainscrollView)
        MainscrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        MainscrollView.contentSize = scrollFrame.size

        //1 frame
        let firstView : UIView = UIView(frame: singleFrame)
        firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        MainscrollView.addSubview(firstView)

        //2 frame
        singleFrame.origin.x = firstView.frame.size.width
        let secondView : UIView = UIView(frame: singleFrame)
        secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        MainscrollView.addSubview(secondView)

        //3 frame
        singleFrame.origin.x = firstView.frame.size.width * 2
        let thirdView : UIView = UIView(frame: singleFrame)
        thirdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        MainscrollView.addSubview(thirdView)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ MainscrollView : UIScrollView) {
        print("in here")
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating function is never triggered.
I have a couple of needs:

1. How can I use correctly the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating? (I need it to trigger the event "page changed" for a pageController element).
2. Can you put me on the right direction to implement some additional graphical effects above the scrollView as objects that enter and exit in the view with a different speed than the scrollView (as Google Calendar Intro, or Evernote Intro, etc.)?

Comment: Some stylistic observations unrelated to the actual problem: `Mainscrollview` should begin with a lowercase letter and should be in camelCase (i.e., `mainScrollView`), and the argument name of `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` should not be `MainscrollView` (e.g., just `scrollView` is fine).

Comment: Also, having the scrollview as a `let` constant would have made the problem obvious at compile time.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you've created `UIScrollView` twice:

```
     var MainscrollView = UIScrollView()
```

and

```
MainscrollView = UIScrollView(frame: singleFrame)
```

So, after setting of delegate your `MainscrollView` created again. You can change your code to set correct frame like that:

```
    MainscrollView.frame = singleFrame
    view.addSubview(MainscrollView)
    MainscrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    MainscrollView.contentSize = scrollFrame.size
```

And you must named your property in camel case - `mainScrollView`

Comment: I see. But after that you recreated your `mainScrollView`.

Comment: I didn't create anything as it's not my question, but the point is, the original version did not answer the question at all. (Now it does more so, because you spotted the real problem of creating the actual instance of the scroll view _after_ setting the delegate, so perhaps edit the answer to not open with the false guess. =)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This fix my issue! Michele